# jQuery Sliders and corresponding input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, input

Basically, this is the deal: I have a dynamically generated bunch of jQuery Sliders, each with a corresponding input field that retrieves the value selected using the slider. This works fine.

The script is this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.nuisance_slider').slider({
        value: 50,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).prev('.nuisance_value').val( ui.value );
        }
    });
    $('.nuisance_value').val( $('.nuisance_slider').slider('value') );
});
```

And the markup this:

```
<input type='hidden' class='nuisance_value' name='a' />
<div class='nuisance_slider'></div>

<input type='hidden' class='nuisance_value' name='b' />
<div class='nuisance_slider'></div>
```

So, when one slider is moved, the input element just above it is updated.

My challenge is this: the markup is part of a major input form, and I need to be able to fill data into this form, and have the sliders adjust themselves to the right positions. Ideally this would just require adding value="35" to input a for instance.

What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance!

Best, Jonas

Answer (score 0):

You would just do something like:

```
//set the input value to 75
$('input[name="a"]').val('75');

//set the slider value
$(".nuisance_slider").slider( "option", "value", 75 );
```

Comment: Well, not quite. I need a general statement like `code`$(this).prev('.nuisance_value').val(ui.value);`code` so that I don't need to set each value, individually.

Comment: Then you need to clarify how you are filling in the values. None of your elements have an ID so I dont know how you are filling each form field.